# How can I as a root user manage folder owned by other users using ubuntu desktop?

Tags: permissions, sudo, desktop-environments

I need to copy files/folder  to a folder but that is owned by another user, infact a installed application by me. So how do I get the rights to copy files/folder to that folder ?

I want to do it via ubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `gksu nautilus`, press enter and enter password. The nautilus(file explorer) will open and you can copy files there as root.  You might have to install program gksu, if it is not already installed on your computer. You can do that by typing the following in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Comment: You're welcome! If it helped, please mark as answered.

Comment: Sure! will accept your answer as soon as I'm allowed to!  it says to wait for 3 mins:)